# JSON data & JavaScript (trying to find error, maybe just syntax)

Tags: javascript, json

It seems like I have a Syntax issue... but I can't quite nail this one. I've gone through a validator but can't seem to iron it out.

```js
var data ={
  "created":"2014-10-17T14:42:39Z     ",

  "lang":"en-US",

  "location":{"city": "Orlando", "country": "United States", "region": "FL     "},

  "results":{
    "units":{"     distance": "mi", "pressure": "ins", "speed": "mph", "temperature": "F     "},
    "wind":{"chill": "76", "direction": "360", "speed": "5     "},
    "atmosphere":{"humidity": "48", "pressure": "29.65", "rising": "0", "visibility": "10     "},
    "astronomy":{"sunrise": "7:26 am", "sunset": "6:51 pm     "},
    "condition":{"code": "33", "date": "Fri, 17 Oct 2014 5:53 am EST", "temp": "76", "text": "Fair     "},
    "forecast":[

      {
        "code":"30",
        "date":"17",
        "Oct":"2014",
        "day":"Fri",
        "high":"80",
        "low":"62",
        "text":"Sunny"

        },{

          "code":"30",
          "date":"18",
          "Oct":"2014",
          "day":"Sat",
          "high":"82",
          "low":"63",
          "text":"Partly Cloudy"

          },{

            "code":"30",
            "date":"19",
            "Oct":"2014",
            "day":"Sun",
            "high":"85",
            "low":"65",
            "text":"Partly Cloudy      "

          }
        ]
      }
      };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="data.json"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>JSON in Console</h1>
  <script>
  console.log(data.data.results.forecast[2].day);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to get the script tag inside the HTML to run and deliver the result in the console window.

Comment: First of all, this isn’t JSON, it’s a JS object in a JS file. Secondly, your `data` object does not contain another property called `data`, so why are you writing `data.data`?! Next time change the error console.

Comment: Change `data.data.results.forecast[2].day` to `data.results.forecast[2].day` in your html.

Comment: That was a typo into the S/O window, in my editor it is only one data being typed and still having an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a hidden illegal character after the word 'created' on the first line